# Set ember.js application root for linked css and js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have an ember.js app (using CLI) that works great locally. When I pushed it up to my server at... www.thesite.com/subfolder    (just sending up /dist) --- the files all get there, but the css and js href's are without the subfolder... This may very well be basic - and unrelated to ember... but I'm stumped... do I need to set a new root or something?

Locally I have `~ /sites/subfolder/files` (which includes "assets")

Remotely I have `mysite.com/subfolder/files` (which includes "assets")

when viewing the remote I get: 404 for `mysite.com/assets/app.css` 
instead of `mysite.com/subfolder/assets/app.css`

Comment: You may need to set the baseUrl in the config/environment.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using ember-cli, and want to host your ember app (including your assets, images, etc) from /subfolder instead of default /.

Change baseURL in config/environment.js
{
    baseURL: '/subfolder',
....
}

Now you can run your 'ember serve' and navigate to localhost:4200/subfolder, your ember app will fire up.

Also make sure you use relative path for all you assets linking.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was using CLI. I had tried that, as @blessenm's suggestion - but then my images went whack... but that was because I copy and pasted a bunch of JSON with a /. Thanks for getting me to look into that again! I'm going to check in the production specific part of the environment. Thanks again.